# VS 15 Community can't create C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm having trouble creating a C++ project in Visual Studio 15 ComEd, with update 3 I think. I have every C++ option installed and I'm still getting an error. I've both modified the installation--removing C++ then re-adding it--and completely uninstalled and reinstalled VS. Still C++ isn't working. I've tried running as Admin and deleting the caches, both didn't go so well.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The apparent issue is that default.vcxproj is from an older version of Visual Studio (assuming you didn't try to install VS2017). I don't know how this situation was created. You might want to post a question at one of the Microsoft forums.

Comment: @rcgldr Okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Check your windows environment variable path to visual studio.

Go to:

```
Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
```

Change the variable:

```
VS140COMNTOOLS
```

To the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
```

Comment: Try this: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/23ba76f1-ad92-41ad-a306-612272e33c73?category=vssetup

Comment: Already did. I cleared the caches and that messed my install. There is no Start menu folder with the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [VS 17 ComEd](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/) and that doesn't have a problem working with C++. Never figured out what the deal with 15 was though.